# Appengine backends -> 500 Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to set up a appengine backend. I configured a backend in the "backends.xml" like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<backends>

    <backend name="order-backend">
        <class>B1</class>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

I can see this backend in my backend like that:

[image]

But if I click on it, the url http://order-backend.myapp.appspot.com returns a 500 Error.

I thougt I maybe need to call a servlet with the backend instance so I tried with a servlet, which is running under "test" like that:

http://order-backend.myapp.appspot.com/test

Whats am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

A GAE backend is what it sounds like, a backend process that runs in the background.  I do not think you can navigate to it in a browser like that.  You might read the backend documentation  [here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/)

Also, A 500 error is an internal error.  There's not much to go on here but you should see some errors in your app engine logs that would point you in the right direction. Also, when I click on your link it forwards me to the "http://my-life.appspot.com/" URL, so I don't see the errors you are mentioning.

Comment: The doc says, I can access them directly: "Both resident and dynamic backends allow you to address tasks to a specific instance of a backend. You can obtain the instance and backend names programmatically; the endpoint takes the form http://[instance].[backend_name].[your_app_id].appspot.com." And why would there be a link if you not access them directly?

Comment: Actually the link was made up, did not know that site really existed :)

Comment: You are correct, I did not realize you could use backends in this way.  It seems a little strange to me to do so but I'm sure there is a valid use case for it.  I did see this though: "Backends can be public, that is, directly exposed in some way to users, or they can be private, not user-facing at all."  do you know if your's is public?  Private is the default.